# How to fix issue with raw xml post not being processed?

Tags: php, xml, server

A third party service does a post request of a raw xml string to the server so it is processed. However, it's not being processed. How do I configure to accept the raw xml string?

This php site was recently migrated to be hosted on BlueHost, from a different provider. Where it was hosted previously, it was able process the xml. Since moving to BlueHost, it's not working. I changed the code slightly to email if it reached there just to see if it's even hitting it and it is not. I checked the access logs and the only thing I could tell is that at the time the third party made the request, it looks like a 406 error. I can't contact the old provider to provide if any server configuration.

What is supposed to happen is that when the third party passes the xml, it sends a copy via email and inserts an entry into the data table. So far, it doesn't seem to be doing that.

So I am not sure as to what could be the issue and where to start looking. Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:**

The code below verifies, that the IP is valid and if so, should process the XML string. I obtained all the IP address from the third party so there is no interruption. I added code to email me if it accessed this page. So far, haven't gotten any emails.

```php
require_once "loader.php";
// Initiate Parse
$Feed = new FeedParser();
$Job = new Job();
$IP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
// Initiate Job Model

if($Job->verifyIP($IP) == false){
    $headers = "From: webapp@certainplace.com\r\n";
    mail('someemail@somewhere.com', 'Failed', 'The following ip failed: '.$IP, $headers);
    die("Your IP address is not white listed. please contact system adminstrator.");
}else{
    $headers = "From: webapp@certainplace.com\r\n";
    mail('someemail@somewhere.com', 'Here', 'Made it here', $headers);  
}

// Capture XML By Key
$xml = file_get_contents('php://input');

if($xml != '') {
    $headers = "From: webapp@certainplace.com\r\n";
    $options = "-fwebapp@certainplace.com";
    mail('someemail@somewhere.com', 'XML Code', $xml, $headers, $options);

    $Job->addXML($xml);
}
```

I found this in the access log provided by BlueHost, when the third party tried to make the request:

```
<ip 1> - - [11/Oct/2019:12:00:24 -0600] "POST /xml_parse/ HTTP/1.1" 406 226 "-" "-" www.certainplace.com <ip 2>
```

So it seems like something is coming through, but the server seems to be blocking the request.

Comment: Could you show some code, or an example? Anything would help

Comment: @ParsaYazdani - I updated my answer. I am not sure if it's a coding change or configuration change I need to make to the server.

Comment: @pmb88 Can you please check your posix queue?

Comment: @HarmSmits How would I do that? I apologize, but I am new to this.